# End kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root FS on unknown-block(179,2)

Tags: boot

My pi-top says this when it tried to boot and I tried the method of holding down shift when turning it on but I can't edit the program! Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 1):

The boot loader cannot find the root partition. There are some possibilities which will fail boot up:

1. The entry for `root=` in `/boot/cmdline.txt` is wrong.
2. The entry in `/etc/fstab` for the root partion is wrong.
3. The root partition isn't formated as `ext4` filesystem
4. There is no root filesystem on the root partition

Comment: None of the items mentioned would be as result of normal operation, right?

Comment: @JanHus Right, they all will fail boot up. I have clarified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, been there, done that. 
I know that does not help  you , but shift to "recover" did not fix 
anything for me either.

Your SD is most likely kaput - probably powered down at wrong time. 
. 
To verify - try reformatting it OUTSIDE Pi.